# Error Sending Email using Gmail with SMTP (Python 3)

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to use SMTP in Python 3.4 to send emails but I am receiving the following error when I run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anna Hughes/Documents/Python Projects/2015.10.16/Mail Application.py", line 9, in <module>
    server.login(user_email, user_password)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 613, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")

user_email = "user@gmail.com"
user_password = "password"
recipient_email = "recipient@gmail.com"
msg = "Test."

server.login(user_email, user_password)

server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.sendmail(user_email, recipient_email, msg)
server.quit()
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have changed the second line to `server = smtplib.SMTP("smpt.gmail.com, 587")` as suggested. That seemed to fix the error, but I am now getting a new one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Anna Hughes/Documents/Python Projects/2015.10.16/Mail Application.py", line 2, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com,587")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 494, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail):

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP("user@gmail.com", "password")
yag.send("recipient@gmail.com", subject="sub", contents="Test.")
```

Install using `pip install yagmail`.

Lots of more tricks can be found on the github page, such as passwordless script.

Answer (score 1):

I can help.

1. See [here](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and turn on.

Then

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com, 587")
server.starttls()
server.login("username","p455w0rd")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps your problem lies with this: 
`server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")`

I've got a few programs that send e-mails, and I use the following format instead: 
    `server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com, 587")`

If you can't see the difference at first, the colon has been changed to a comma.
Hope this fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
import smtplib
Server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
Server.starttls()
Server.login("EMAIL_YOUR","YOUR_PASSWORD")
msg="Hello, Its the Message!"
Server.sendmail("whom_2_send@gmail.com","your_email@gmail.com",msg)
print("email send succesfully") #Just for confirmation
Server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(email, password, message)
server.quit()
```